Problem with Guacamole to access Cisco routers with ssh
Just installed Guacamole with Docker and tried to log in on Cisco routers with ssh.
First, Guacamole get a response from the router and ask for a login.

Once I entered the login and press enter nothing happens

The log looks like this:

But when I connect to a "standard" ssh server, everything works fine.

Here are the logs:

The only difference is the reception of the authentication methods.
Any idea?
Did someone already succeed to ssh to Cisco routers ?
Thank you
